# Preparatory git merge

Tags: git

Let's say I have a branch `develop`. From this branch I branch with `git checkout -b feature` and work on it for a while. When I want to eventually make a **merge request** to merge my branch into `develop`, is it a **valid** and/or **sensible** approach to first `git merge develop` while on `feature` to reduce the amount of work the person responsible for the state of `develop` has to do?

Comment: It depends, but most often, yes.

Comment: Or better yet use `git rebase`, which will often result in a cleaner history.

Comment: We rebase and squash, but after starting to answer that and considering some practices of different teams in my workplace, I would say this is opinion based. If you want the feature branch to remain complete in the history as is, than I would say most often no (and already we have varying opinions). The added "squares" in the tree just make it less readable, and there really isn't any preference to whom has to do the hard work in the generic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of your branch/merge workflow are for your team to decide, so really the question as asked is opinion-based and should probably be closed.

In the spirit of being a bit more helpful than that: the closest potentially-factual question would be, what are pros and cons of doing such a merge.

- As you note, you will get more of the merge work out of the way, by the person who's familiar with the intent of the feature branch's changes; that's a PRO
- But then again, that person may *not* be the most familiar with the intent of the other changes on `develop`; that's a CON that arguably cancels out with the above PRO
- You will get an extra merge in history.  Some people are pathologically opposed to these (and, in come cases, most) merge commits.  This borders back on "opinion", so I'll just say it's a difference.
- You test the combined state on the branch; that's a PRO; *but* it must be tempered, because you still don't know that more stuff won't get merged to develop ahead of you.  (If multiple PR's are open at once, it's a sure thing that it will happen to all but one of them.)

An alternative, with its own pros and cons, would be to rebase your feature branch to the develop tip before the PR.  Functionally this is similar to the above, but the pros and cons are a bit different.

- It results in potentially *many* commit states that have not been tested.  If you generally have a good automated test suite, then creating untested states that might fail the tests is a loss of trouble-shooting capability.
- It not only avoids the "backwards merge" commit, but *might* (for PR's that don't get stacked up) avoid the forward-merge too.  So if you really don't like merge commits, that's a pro.

Yet another alternative is to do the merge just to figure out any conflicts and test the combined state, and then back the merge out of the feature branch.  This avoids the "extra" merge commit, but it means (unless you can use git rerere to mitigate this issue) that you have to resolve any conflicts twice.

**Bottom line**

There are many different workflows, and many different opinions about which are "correct".  Only your team can decide what works for your team, by being informed of the options and their consequences.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely.

I would say that it not only is sensible, but also should be mandatory, because doing one final merge from `develop`, and **test the merged code** to make sure that it doesn't break anything else on `develop`, is supposed to be the feature developer's job.

And then there is the courtesy to the `develop` maintainer you already mentioned.